# StaleStateException: Hibernate tries update instead of insert?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I've got the following domain mapped to a mysql-database:

```
class User {
  String username
  String passwordHash 

static mapping={
    table 'team'
    version false
    passwordHash column: 'Password' 
    id column: 'username', name: 'username'
   }
}
```

When trying to execute the save() of an instance, hibernate always executes this query:

> Hibernate: update team set Password=? where username=?

calling of save():

```
def save(){
   def userInstance = new User()
   userInstance.username = "test"
   userInstance.passwordHash = "abcd"
   if(!userInstance.save(flush:true)){
       //
   }
}
```

I already tried to change flush:true to insert:true. No effect.

Comment: Have you made sure username `test` is not pre-existing?

Comment: @dmahapatro the table is completely empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I missed to inform you in the last question. You have to use generator as `assigned` if you are using your own identifier and assigning your own `id`. So:

```
id column: 'username', name: 'username', generator: 'assigned'
```

Moreover I would suggest to use the domain name as `Team` for table `team` instead of `User`, I am not sure that will play well otherwise.

Comment: Thinking about it as a whole concept, i must say (without having even scratched on the surface) this is absolutely logical.